# Docker-Compose Error response from daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I generated a cluster successfully. Then, I need to run a container with compose. So, I used docker-machine to ssh into the first node (Leader). I ran the following command:

```
docker pull docker/compose
```

I got the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Any help ?

How can I solve this error ? I searched a lot and I tried a lot, nothing works :(

Comment: What are you trying to pull here? neither there is a image `docker/compose` nor `docker:compose`. You need to install `docker-compose` using pip. `pip install docker-compose`

Comment: When I ran: pip install docker-compose, I got: -sh: pip: not found. Then, I ran: apt-get -y install python-pip, I got: -sh: apt-get: not found. What should I do ?

Comment: Try `apt install -y python-pip` or `apk add python-pip` or `yum install python-pip` depending on the distribution

Comment: @TarunLalwani All of them not found, is that normal ?!

Comment: What are you using? Which OS?

Comment: @TarunLalwani macOS Sierra 10.12.6 I ran them in node 1 (Leader).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152467/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-mariam).

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes occures when there is an issue with the docker engine. Simply restarting the engine could bring back the functionality (I had the same issue just two minutes ago :D).

So, simply type:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

or however your docker engine can be restarted.

Comment: I restarted a lot, I even uninstall docker and re-install it. Nothing works. When I ran: sudo systemctl restart docker, I got: sudo: systemctl: command not found

Comment: This command depends on the OS you are using. systemctl is often available in Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I get a similar error when i run the following:

```
docker pull docker/compose
```

Looking at docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/tags/) it looks like docker/compose does not have a "latest" tag. Specifying a specific tag works for me.

```
docker pull docker/compose:1.15.0
```

Comment: I got same error even when I specified tag: docker pull docker/compose:1.15.0

Comment: The error message mentions an IP address which looks like a local DNS server (port 53). Is that DNS able to resolve registry-1.docker.io?

Comment: I don't know. Could you please tell me how to check it ?

Comment: I think dig is the tool of your choice if you're on linux. Try:

    dig registry-1.docker.io

Comment: Then compare your results with what you get when running dig @8.8.8.8 registry-1.docker.io (which uses the google public DNS, especially the ANSWERS section).

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps

1. Open VM running on Virtual Box
2. open file with `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf`
3. Modify the entry **10.0.2.3** with **8.8.8.8**
4. save the file and now you will be able to **download/pull** the image